# バイト配列のエクセルを開く

Tags: c#, excel

C#で、DBに格納してある、エクセルファイルをバイト配列に読み込み、エクセルを開きたいのですが、方法をご存知の方お教えください。
バイト配列に展開されている前提のコードをお願いします。

Comment: 質問の主旨は、以下のソースコードで、Bookを作成する時点で、例外が発生し、解決したいことです。           //ブック読み込み(テンプレート)
            var excelTemplate = new ExcelReport(_db, _logger) { TemplateId = FdId.FD1210 };

            byte[] buffer = excelTemplate.GetExcelTemplate();
  
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(buffer);
            //IWorkbook book = WorkbookFactory.Create(stream);
            XSSFWorkbook book = new XSSFWorkbook(stream);尚、エクセルは、Office2013、NPOIは最新版を使用しています。

Comment: 質問内容は後からでも [編集] 出来ますので、コメントではなくぜひ本文へ追記してください。

Answer (score 1):

`buffer` の内容を一時ファイルに書き込んで `XSSFWorkbook` インスタンスの生成に利用し、用が済んだらその一時ファイルを削除する、では駄目でしょうか。

```
//ブック読み込み(テンプレート)
var excelTemplate = new ExcelReport(_db, _logger) { TemplateId = FdId.FD1210 };
byte[] buffer = excelTemplate.GetExcelTemplate();
string tempFilePath = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(tempFilePath, buffer);
XSSFWorkbook book = new XSSFWorkbook(tempFilePath);

// （何らかの処理）

// 処理が終わったら一時ファイルを削除
System.IO.File.Delete(tempFilePath);
```

Comment: 試行錯誤を繰り返し、一時ファイルを使わずに解決出来ました。テンプレートが正しくDBに反映されていなかったのが、原因でした。例外が発生する原因はわかりませんが、空白のシートがDBに書き込まれていたと思われます。ご回答感謝です。

Comment: この回答とは別の方法で解決したようでしたら、ご自身でその内容を回答し、その回答を承認することをお勧めします。別の人が同様の現象に遭遇したときに、その回答が役に立つかもしれません。　参考１：https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer　参考２：https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1747/%E8%B3%AA%E5%95%8F%E3%81%8C%E8%87%AA%E5%B7%B1%E8%A7%A3%E6%B1%BA%E3%81%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%81%9F%E5%A0%B4%E5%90%88　よろしくお願いします :)